# wp_options table doesn't exist. How to fix?

Tags: wordpress

Being a noob at MYSQL, I accidentally deleted the wp_options table of my site in phpmyadmin!  I have a backup database but it's too large and exceeds the max limit.  I contacted host and they're having trouble with the sql file.

If I were to do a fresh install of wordpress, is there a simple way to keep all my data and just import the other tables into a fresh install of wordpress that would have the options? I can re-customize everything. Is there any vital, non-replaceable content in wp_options table that can't be replaced.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read here https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

```
The Options set under the Administration > Settings panel are stored in the wp_options table.
```

For myself, I would reinstall a dummy version of Wordpress, `export the wp_options` table in MySQL with the default settings. Then import it back to my current Wordpress installation.

Perhaps some options which you have changed over the time are now default, until you set them back like it was before.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1. Add `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` to `wp-config.php` and reload the admin page. It will repair the tables. Now you can remove it from `wp-config.php`.
2. Export the deleted table (ex:`wp_options`) from another WordPress and import it. Now edit the URL and name.