# Critical error when installing Wordpress through XAMPP locally?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

I want to install Wordpress Locally with XAMPP but run into a critical error during the second step of the installation. I'm following the easy steps on [this](https://themeisle.com/blog/install-xampp-and-wordpress-locally/) guide.

As you can see here, I've made a database called "webshop":
[MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUsLZ.png)

And correctly entered the information in the Wordpress setup:
[Setup Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOWrD.png)

But it will end up with this error message:
[Critical error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4HGP.png)

So as workaround I filled in the necessary info into the wp-config-sample.php file, and renamed it to wp-config.php like so:

[WP-config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx50F.png)

But end up getting this error message when I go to the website directory on my browser:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'webshop.wp_options' doesn't exist in D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\wp-db.php:2056 Stack trace: #0 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\wp-db.php(2056): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT option_n...') #1 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\wp-db.php(1945): wpdb->_do_query('SELECT option_n...') #2 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\wp-db.php(2695): wpdb->query('SELECT option_n...') #3 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\option.php(284): wpdb->get_results('SELECT option_n...') #4 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\functions.php(1730): wp_load_alloptions() #5 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\load.php(752): is_blog_installed() #6 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed() #7 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-config.php(96): require_once('D:\Tools\XAMP\h...') #8 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-load.php(50): require_once('D:\Tools\XAMP\h...') #9 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('D:\Tools\XAMP\h...') #10 D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\index.php(17): require('D:\Tools\XAMP\h...') #11 {main} thrown in D:\Tools\XAMP\htdocs\webshop\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2056

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287784/wp-options-table-doesnt-exist-how-to-fix

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It might fit better on superuser, serverfault, or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. Also, please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Apart from that, this site is for english content, and dutch (or other language) screenshots help even less than screenshots in general. [ask].

Answer (score 4):

By using an older version of XAMPP I figured out that the latest version of Wordpress is incompatible with the Latest version of XAMPP (8). I used 7 and it works the way it should now.

Answer (score 1):

Will I tried And YAY!! therefor see the solution that i come with:

**1-** Go to [Download WordPress from HERE!!!!!!](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer) then **under On my computer** select win/mac/Linux then go down and download the one that work with your operating system.

**2-** Then install **It's simple**

 **Noties:** WordPress will install phpmyadmin and Apache, therefor it will not need Xampp. **It's a stand alone**

**3-** copy the wordpress files from the installation

> **C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.8.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs**
>
> To
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress**

and then edit the wp-config.php in xampp copied wordpress.

in the wp-config.php

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'Go_Hacker_Nothing_to_see_here XD' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

save it.

**-4** edit the User's and the GRANT in the xampp phpMyAdmin
Login then go to DB called phpmyadmin => PRIVILEGES => new User
[image: PRIVILEGES]

add the user you saw in define( 'DB_USER', '**bn_wordpress**' );
and then add the same paswoord you putted in **wp-config.php** => **Go_Hacker_Nothing_to_see_here XD**

**5-** go to wordpress phpmyadmin, for me it was http://127.0.0.1:81/phpmyadmin/

Login as root + the password that you set on wordpress installation.

Go to Database bitnami_wordpress then export as .sql then go.
[image: export]

**6-** go to xampp phpmyadmin Login as root or whatever then add new Database and call it as same as in the wp-config.php  define( 'DB_NAME', '**bitnami_wordpress**' );

With this database selected go to import "Next to export" and select the .sql file from your downloads folder.

**-7** edit the port in table= wp_options for **home** and **siteurl**
or just put them as http://localhost/wordpress/

**8-** with the bitnami_wordpress database selected go to PRIVILEGES then the wordpress user that you created select edit-PRIVILEGES
then go to Database next to global and select the database you created for wordpress and press go. then select all and go.

[image: edit-PRIVILEGES]

[image]

**9-** in the wp-config.php edit this

> define('WP_TEMP_DIR',
> 'C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.8.3-0/apps/wordpress/tmp');
>
> To
> define('WP_TEMP_DIR', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\temp');

**Dont forget to create the file there**

**10-** Go To http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin
Login with the setup username and password, and delete all post in there!

**11-** Go to sittings then permalink and set **Common Settings** to **Plain**

**BTW:**WordPress Can Not be Installed With Xampp higher than **8.0.14**

So if you want it to be with xampp [Download 8.0.14](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/8.0.14/xampp-windows-x64-8.0.14-1-VS16-installer.exe) and uninstall the old one If you dont want to do all 11 steps.

**BTW:** you can uninstall wordpress we dont need it anymore

If you want to ask why all of that!!. i will till you because the MySQL server from the wordpress instalation is extremly slow and you dont want to run 2 port and 2 MySQL

**Let me know what you got :)**