# Table 'database.wp_options' doesn't exist error log in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Please I need help its my firs time to setup and I can't install wordpress in my localhost server IIS I'm using latest PHP, MySQL and IIS.

Here is my Debug LOG:

[15-Jan-2022 02:53:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'cswebsite.wp_options' doesn't exist in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\wp-db.php:2056
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\wp-db.php(2056): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT option_v...')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\wp-db.php(1945): wpdb->_do_query('SELECT option_v...')
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\wp-db.php(2581): wpdb->query('SELECT option_v...')
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\functions.php(1734): wpdb->get_var('SELECT option_v...')
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\load.php(752): is_blog_installed()
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed()
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-config.php(97): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
#8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-admin\install.php(36): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
#9 {main}
thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cswebsite\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2056

Comment: Perhaps this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287784/wp-options-table-doesnt-exist-how-to-fix . I suggests that you make this as a habit; search for that partial general error message (e.g. _"PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'cswebsite.wp_options' doesn't exist"_ ) in SO first before you post a question. Some "things" have been existing for quite a while and I don't think you're the first one to get an error like this.

Comment: is this `cswebsite.wp_options` even available in ur DB? seems like you dont have the necessary DB

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to make a fresh local install of WP with no previous versions installed.

I saw a couple of posts ([example](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/680)) suggesting it's a PHP version problem with WP5.8.x, and reverting to PHP8.0 works.  And guess what, it did.

(I was using homebrew, and 'brew install php@8.0' doesn't create the symlinks you need to do a 'brew link php@8.0' afterwards.  Also, it put libphp.so in a different place (why, Lord, why?) so you need to change your httpd.conf as well.  Oh, and you probably need to do 'brew remove php' before you start the downgrade)

Hope this works for you...